# Change a specific row data of a HTML table as well as database using AJAX call

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, web, html-table

I have a database table like this -

```
    -----------------------------------|
    ID         |    Name  |   Status   |
    -----------------------------------|
    101             John        0      |
                                       |
    102             Robert      1      |
                                       |
    103             David       0      |
    -----------------------------------|
```

By featching this database I am creating a html table (shown below) in which each row has a button to change its current status in the table and also in the backend database. i.e. 0 becomes 1 and 1 becomes 0.

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Status</th>
    <th>Action</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>101</td>
    <td> John </td>
    <td> 0 </td>
    <td><button>Change Status</button> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>102</td>
    <td> Robert </td>
    <td> 1 </td>
    <td><button>Change Status</button> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>103</td>
    <td> David </td>
    <td> 0 </td>
    <td><button>Change Status</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This should be done without refreshing the page. So I think I should make an AJAX call to the server with the ID and the status of that ID. But I don't understand how to do it.

Comment: You should try it yourself. It is pretty basic stuff what you do with ajax. Just pass the id and status in data and show some kind of notification next to the button if the operation was successful using the success callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First add a data attribute on the `button` tag and output the ID in its value, and create another data attribute for current status, so that button tag looks something like this:

```
<button data-id="5" data-status="0">Change Status</button>
```

Then use jQuery's `ajax` method to send Ajax call to server, something like below:

```
$("button").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    data = {row_id: $(this).data('id'), current_status: $(this).data('status')};
    $.ajax({
        type : "post",
        data: data,
        url: "URL_TO_SERVER_FILE_WHICH_WILL_HANDLE DATA",
        success: function(result){
            // show message here and also change current status on data 
            // attribute of button and in the status column of table

        }
    });
});
```